# LinkedList implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am currently reading through an algorithm book and trying to implement everything as I go. I am also learning python at the same time. This is my implementation of a simple linked-list. I am mainly concerned with whether the code looks "looks python like" any tips on how I can refactor would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Linked(object):
    # init
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def add(self, data):
        temp = Node(data, None, None)
        if (self.head is None):
            self.head = temp
            self.tail = temp
        else:
            self.tail.setAfter(temp)
            temp.setBefore(self.tail)
            self.tail = temp

    def find(self, data):
        if (self.head is None):
            return "Empty List"
        else:
            current = self.head
            while (current is not None):
                if (current.element() is data):
                    return current
                current = current.next()
        return "Element not in List"

    def remove(self, data):
        if (self.head is None):
            return "Empty List"
        elif(self.find(data).element() is data):
            temp = self.find(data)
            if (temp is self.head and temp is self.tail):
                self.head = None
                self.tail = None
            elif (temp is self.head):
                self.head = temp.next()
                self.head.setBefore(None)
                return
            elif (temp is self.tail):
                temp.before.setAfter(None)
                return
            else:
                temp.before.setAfter(temp.after)
                temp.after.setBefore(temp.before)

    def iterator(self):
        if (self.head is None):
            return "Empty List"
        else:
            current = self.head
            while (current is not None):
                print(current.element())
                current = current.next()


class Node(object):
    # init
    def __init__(self, data=None, before=None, after=None):
        self.data = data
        self.before = before
        self.after = after

    def element(self):
        return self.data

    def setBefore(self, before):
        self.before = before

    def setAfter(self, after):
        self.after = after

    def next(self):
        return self.after
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make your life a lot easier if you used the fact that Python allows you to give custom classes built-in behavior. This allows you to define classes for which e.g. `a + b` is defined or, as in this case `for x in obj`.

The way Python allows this is via so called dunder (short for double-underscore) or magic methods. These are special method names which get invoked under certain circumstances.

If you ask Python to iterate over an object `obj`, it calls the method `obj.__iter__` (or at least tries to). If you write `a + b` it first calls `a.__add__(b)` and if that does not work `b.__radd__(a)`.

A linked list is predestined to have this method:

```
class Linked(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def add(self, data):
        temp = Node(data, None, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = temp
        else:
            self.tail.next = temp
            temp.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = temp

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            yield current.data
            current = current.next
        raise StopIteration
```

Together with a greatly simplified `Node` class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, prev=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)
```

This already allows simple things like iterating:

```
l = Linked()
l.add(1)
l.add(3)
print(list(l))
# [1, 3]
for x in l:
    print(x)
# 1
# 3
```

The other methods can then take advantage of the fact that it is easy to iterate over the object:

```
class Linked(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        if data is not None:
            for x in data:
                self.append(x)

    def append(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = Node(data)
        else:
            node = Node(data, self.tail)
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.next

    def find(self, data):
        for x in self:
            if x.data == data:
                return x
        return None

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(list(self))

    def remove(self, data):
        x = self.find(data)
        if x is None:
            return
        if x is self.head:
            if x is self.tail:
                self.head = self.tail = None
            else:
                self.head = x.next
                self.head.prev = None
        elif x is self.tail:
            x.prev.next = None
        else:
            x.prev.next = x.next
            x.next.prev = x.prev
```

Here I modified the `__iter__` method to yield the nodes, not just the data, removed the manual raising of `StopIteration` (it is not needed and actually deprecated in Python 3), added a `__len__` and `__repr__` method for convenience (the latter gets called when you call `repr(obj)` or when you just enter the variable name in an interactive session), renamed `add` to `append` (to mirror the normal `list` interface), added an optional argument to the constructor to ease initializing a linked list from an iterable and used the optional arguments of `Node` to make the `append` method slightly easier to read.

Also note that your class is actually a doubly-linked list, since each node has a pointer to the previous and the next node.

Comment: Okay, so I did some reading up on dunder methods. Just to clarify, Since I pass `object` as a parameter when I define my classes they both inherit the methods from `object`. You then overrode those methods in `__iter__`, `__len__`, and `__repr__`. Is that correct?

Comment: @k4iru No, not really. The inheritance from `object` does not have anything to do with it. This also works with old-style classes in Python 2, which do not inherit from `object`. It is just a feature of Python that it looks for these method names. Also note that in Python 3 all classes inherit from `object` (they are new-style classes) so you don't need to actually do it explicitly (but it is ok for backwards compatibility).

Comment: I see, so Python just has a list of built in dunder methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the extra parens.  Returning strings in cases where the list is empty is pretty odd, too.  iterator() doesn't work like I'd expect it to.  element() seems like a weird name for a getter, and I think it'd be more idiomatic to not have a getter.  I'd try to get find and remove to use the iterator.